# What is an alternative method of using random.choices() in python 3.5

Tags: random, python-3.5

Since, random.choices() is not available in python 3.5, is there any alternative method for this function?

Comment: I've read the documentation section and it has methods that are only valid if the probabilities are integers in the case of python 3.5. Is there any other method I can use?  https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html

Comment: `random.choices` is written in Python, so you could simply copy [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/00923c63995e34cdc25d699478f113de99a69df9/Lib/random.py#L397-L420) for that method into your codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied the code from python 3.6 to as suggested by Mark Dickinson

```
from itertools import accumulate as _accumulate, repeat as _repeat
from bisect import bisect as _bisect
import random
def choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1):
    """Return a k sized list of population elements chosen with replacement.
    If the relative weights or cumulative weights are not specified,
    the selections are made with equal probability.
    """
    n = len(population)
    if cum_weights is None:
        if weights is None:
            _int = int
            n += 0.0    # convert to float for a small speed improvement
            return [population[_int(random.random() * n)] for i in _repeat(None, k)]
        cum_weights = list(_accumulate(weights))
    elif weights is not None:
        raise TypeError('Cannot specify both weights and cumulative weights')
    if len(cum_weights) != n:
        raise ValueError('The number of weights does not match the population')
    bisect = _bisect
    total = cum_weights[-1] + 0.0   # convert to float
    hi = n - 1
    return [population[bisect(cum_weights, random.random() * total, 0, hi)]
            for i in _repeat(None, k)]
```

now you can use `choices` function peacefully!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't falling head over heels in love with Venkatesh Mondi's answer, but it's totally functional.

```
import random

def random_choices(population, weights=None, k=1):
    """
    This function achieves the same result. 
    If weights is not provided, it returns a list of k random choices made using random.
    choice with no weighting. If weights is provided, it first normalizes the weights by 
    dividing each weight by the sum of all the weights, and then returns a list of k random 
    choices made using random.choice with the normalized weights.
    """
    if weights is None:
        return [random.choice(population) for _ in range(k)]
    total = sum(weights)
    weights = [weight/total for weight in weights]
    cumulative_weights = [sum(weights[:i+1]) for i in range(len(weights))]
    return [population[cumulative_weights.index(next(x for x in cumulative_weights if x >= random.random()))] for _ in range(k)]
    #note you may also do something like: 
    return population[weights.index(random.choice(weights))]
print(random_choices(population, weights=weights, k=1)[0])
```

here's an alternative i have been using for a while now, I'm not sure if someone wrote it first or if i wrote it though.